# Create a new variable which is min values of two variables in Python

Tags: python, pandas, min

I have a pd dataframe. What I am trying to do is generating a new variable whose values are the min between another two variables.
For example, suppose I have:

```
   a  b  
0  1  0  
1  5  1  
2  7  3  
3  3  5
```

I want to create a new variable C that looks like the following:

```
   a  b  c  
0  1  0  0
1  5  1  1
2  7  3  3
3  3  5  3
```

I tried to write a loop to do it, but since I have over 30k observations, it takes way too long. `min` doesn't seem to do what I want. Is there a concise way to solve it? Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 5):

In this case you can use:

```
df['c'] = df[['a', 'b']].min(axis=1)
```

So you're subsetting the columns you want (using `df[['a', 'b']]`) then applying the `min` function across the value of the columns instead of rows, leaving you a series you can assign as column `c`.

Answer (score 2):

Here 's one approach with [`numpy.minimum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.minimum.html) -

```
df['c'] = np.minimum(df.a,df.b)
```

Thus, you are basically selecting between those two columns for the minimum values and creating a new column with those.

Runtime test with `30k observations/rows` -

```
In [153]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,9,(30000,2)),columns=[['a','b']])

In [154]: %timeit df['c'] = df[['a', 'b']].min(axis=1)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.15 ms per loop # @Jon Clements's soln

In [155]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,9,(30000,2)),columns=[['a','b']])

In [156]: %timeit df['c'] = np.minimum(df.a,df.b)
1000 loops, best of 3: 602 µs per loop
```

Comment: Much nicer when only two arrays are required :)